# Find same Provider Ids and merge into one and also merge services of same provider id in one Array of Provider Object

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, json, api

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "successfully retrieved",
    "data": [
        {
            "providerId": 826172,
            "profile": null,
            "service": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Hair Cutting",
                "description": "This is to cut hairs",
                "serviceThumbnail": null,
                "defaultPriceInAED": 20,
                "defaultDurationInMin": 30
            }
        },
        {
            "providerId": 826173,
            "profile": null,
            "service": {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Hair Coloring",
                "description": "This is to color hairs",
                "serviceThumbnail": null,
                "defaultPriceInAED": 20,
                "defaultDurationInMin": 30
            }
        },
        {
            "providerId": 826173,
            "profile": null,
            "service": {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Nail Cutting",
                "description": "This is for Nail cutting service",
                "serviceThumbnail": null,
                "defaultPriceInAED": 20,
                "defaultDurationInMin": 30
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: please show us what you have tried

Comment: thanks for comment issue has been solved :)

Comment: i need same provider ids service object will be merge in one object

Answer (score 0):

It is very unclear from your question, that what you want to achieve. Seems you want to group `providerId` and its data if same. If so, you can try this:

```js
var value = { "success": true, "message": "successfully retrieved", "data": [ { "providerId": 826172, "profile": null, "service": { "id": 1, "name": "Hair Cutting", "description": "This is to cut hairs", "serviceThumbnail": null, "defaultPriceInAED": 20, "defaultDurationInMin": 30 } }, { "providerId": 826173, "profile": null, "service": { "id": 2, "name": "Hair Coloring", "description": "This is to color hairs", "serviceThumbnail": null, "defaultPriceInAED": 20, "defaultDurationInMin": 30 } }, { "providerId": 826173, "profile": null, "service": { "id": 3, "name": "Nail Cutting", "description": "This is for Nail cutting service", "serviceThumbnail": null, "defaultPriceInAED": 20, "defaultDurationInMin": 30 } }, { "providerId": 826173, "profile": null, "service": { "id": 3, "name": "Nail Cutting 5", "description": "This is for Nail cutting service", "serviceThumbnail": null, "defaultPriceInAED": 20, "defaultDurationInMin": 30 } } ]};

var result = value.data.reduce((acc, elem)=>{
 getIndex = acc.findIndex(val=>val.providerId==elem.providerId);
 getIndex==-1 ?  (elem.service=[elem.service], acc.push(elem)) : acc[getIndex].service = [elem.service, ...acc[getIndex].service]
return acc; 
},[]);

console.log(result);
```

I hope it helps. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks buddy you save my time

Answer (score 0):

```js
var value = { "success": true, "message": "successfully retrieved", "data": [ { "providerId": 826172, "profile": null, "service": { "id": 1, "name": "Hair Cutting", "description": "This is to cut hairs", "serviceThumbnail": null, "defaultPriceInAED": 20, "defaultDurationInMin": 30 } }, { "providerId": 826173, "profile": null, "service": { "id": 2, "name": "Hair Coloring", "description": "This is to color hairs", "serviceThumbnail": null, "defaultPriceInAED": 20, "defaultDurationInMin": 30 } }, { "providerId": 826173, "profile": null, "service": { "id": 3, "name": "Nail Cutting", "description": "This is for Nail cutting service", "serviceThumbnail": null, "defaultPriceInAED": 20, "defaultDurationInMin": 30 } }, { "providerId": 826173, "profile": null, "service": { "id": 3, "name": "Nail Cutting 5", "description": "This is for Nail cutting service", "serviceThumbnail": null, "defaultPriceInAED": 20, "defaultDurationInMin": 30 } } ]};

var result = value.data.reduce((acc, elem)=>{
 getIndex = acc.findIndex(val=>val.providerId==elem.providerId);
 getIndex==-1 ?  (elem.service=[elem.service], acc.push(elem)) : acc[getIndex].service = [elem.service, ...acc[getIndex].service]
return acc; 
},[]);

console.log(result);
```